# How to restart some specific services on a server via batch file when CPU usage high?

Tags: batch-file

We have a server where 2 services are running constantly. Sometimes these services consume over 90% CPU for ex: 100%. Restarting these services returns to normal cpu usage. I need a script/batch file so that it will constantly monitor CPU usage and if usage is high, then restart those services

Comment: I dont have much idea how to do.. so i am asking for help.. i tried to google out but got some commands to check cpu usage in cmd..i could not think beyond that.. Your help would be appreciated :) Kindly help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow as new member remember to use the Accept button to accept the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Echo OFF

SET    "SERVICE=Themes"
SET /A "MAXUSAGE=95"
SET /A "INTERVAL=5"

:LOOP
For /F %%P in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage ^| FINDSTR "[0-9]"') do (
    IF %%P GTR %MAXUSAGE% (
        Echo [%TIME:~0,8%] CPU Usage: %%P%% Reached the limit: %MAXUSAGE%%%
        Echo Restarting %SERVICE% ...
        SC STOP  "%SERVICE%" 1>NUL
        SC START "%SERVICE%" 1>NUL
        Echo Service restarted.
    ) ELSE (
         Echo [%TIME:~0,8%] CPU Usage: %%P%%
    )
)
Ping -n %INTERVAL% Localhost >NUL
GOTO :LOOP
```

**Output:**

```
[10:55:31] CPU Usage: 19%
[10:55:36] CPU Usage: 4%
[10:55:42] CPU Usage: 38% Reached the limit: 25%
Restarting Themes ...
Service restarted.
[10:55:47] CPU Usage: 23%
[10:55:52] CPU Usage: 2%
[10:55:57] CPU Usage: 16%
```

For more precission maybe you want to check the current CPU percentage of the executable associated to the service using:

```
wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process get Name,PercentProcessor
Time
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:again
SET "load="
for /f "skip=1" %%L in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do IF NOT defined load SET load=%%L
IF %load% lss 70 GOTO wait
::
::
::
ECHO load is %load%%% - restart procedures
:wait
timeout /t 5 >nul
GOTO again
```

the WMIC command outputs 3 lines. The first is simply 'loadpercentage' and can be skipped. the second is the load-percentage and is placed into `load`. the `if not defined` ensures that any succeeding line does not change `load` - and that's why `load` is set to [nothing] before the `wmic`

Checking load against the required load is obvious - insert your restart commands as you desire. The message is just for information.

The timeout is a primitive arrangement to allow the job just to run until terminated. the `5` is 5 seconds between loops. alter at will. the `>nul` suppresses `timeout`'s countdown.

Possible to omit this completely if you want to use task scheduler to control repeats, or possibly use `CHOICE` if you want more control.